# Why does tomcat7 log into both catalina.out and catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log?

Tags: tomcat, openbsd

On OpenBSD 5.2, the default installation of tomcat-7.0.29 seems to be logging all errors into both `catalina.out` and `catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log`.

```
Cns# ll /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.*
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat      3067 Jan 16 20:47 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-16.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat   1313285 Jan 17 21:47 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-17.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat     19668 Jan 18 17:33 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-18.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat      2479 Jan 23 15:25 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-23.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat      1580 Jan 26 22:58 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-26.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat     48165 Jan 27 19:30 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-27.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat     34526 Jan 28 16:41 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-28.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat    141985 Jan 29 23:56 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-29.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat    123254 Jan 30 23:25 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-30.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat    145209 Jan 31 22:30 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-01-31.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat      2615 Feb  1 09:01 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-01.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat     10068 Feb  2 19:18 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-02.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat     50541 Feb  3 23:49 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-03.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat     17519 Feb  4 21:29 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-04.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat      1158 Feb  5 22:18 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-05.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat    179466 Feb  6 23:51 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-06.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat  14585534 Feb  7 14:15 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2013-02-07.log
-rw-r--r--  1 _tomcat  _tomcat  16680119 Feb  7 14:15 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

(Note how the total files size of `catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log` is about the same as `catalina.out`, and the logs do seem duplicated.)

**Is there a way to make it log only into `catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log`, and not into `catalina.out`?**

Comment: I prefer to keep catalina.out and rotate it. I de-configure catalina.xxx.log as in the most general case it contains less messages (it ignores `System.out` and `System.err`; programmers sometimes use these in a hurry).

Comment: @kubanczyk: How exactly did you de-configure catalina.xxx.log?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985958/what-is-the-difference-between-catalina-out-and-catalina-yyyy-mm-dd-log-log

Answer (score 11):

After reading some info at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html, it seems like commenting out or removing all mentions of `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler` from `/etc/tomcat/logging.properties` should do the trick.

After that, somehow the file still gets opened up for writing by tomcat (as `stdout` and `stderr`), but it doesn't seem to be puffed up with anything anymore.

```
Cns# stat /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
1136 3949577 -rw-r--r-- 1 _tomcat _tomcat 15763648 16695929 "Feb  7 14:58:46 2013" "Feb  7 14:58:37 2013" "Feb  7 14:58:37 2013" 16384 32672 0 /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
Cns# fstat | fgrep -e USER -e 3949577
USER     CMD          PID   FD MOUNT        INUM MODE       R/W    SZ|DV
_tomcat  java        8994    1 /var      3949577 -rw-r--r--   w 16695929
_tomcat  java        8994    2 /var      3949577 -rw-r--r--   w 16695929
Cns#
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions supported by Tomcat wiki:

- Prevent application to log on `System.out` or `System.err` using logging frameworks.
- Suppress capture it by `swallowOutput`. [Where does System.out go?](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q6) 
  First two steps of [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26044829/3660512) how to do this.

additionally one remark about rolling it. [How do I rotate catalina.out?](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q10)