# How to turn off all tomcat log rotation

Tags: logging, tomcat

I want to manage log rotation on my server using logrotate, however Tomcat performs its own log rotation which interacts badly with logrotate, and I can't find a way to turn it off. My Tomcat instance currently produces 5 types of log:

- catalina.2018-01-17.log
- mysite_access.2018-01-17.log
- localhost.2018-01-17.log
- host-manager.2018-01-17.log
- manager.2018-01-17.log

After some googling I have discovered that I can disable rotation for the 'mysite' logs by adding `rotatable="false"` into the appropriate `<Value>` element in server.xml, but none of the other logs have corresponding `<Value>` elements.

The logs seems to be configured by the logging.properties file, but I can't find a 'turn rotation off' option for this file. Can anyone help? I'm using Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Same question on stackoverflow for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365808/how-to-turn-off-all-tomcat-log-rotation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably using JULI logging as the default in your tomcat instance.  Try this

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = false
```

In logging.properties.

There are some samples online if you search for that property.

If you're not using those logs for anything, you can just remove or rename off the logging.properties file to stop using JULI logging.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're coming to it from the wrong perspective.  There is nothing inherently novel about `logrotate`, in fact, it usually gets run from [`cron`](http://mdoc.su/o/cron.8) once a day, which can result in [funny situations where you have no idea why your `logrotate` directions aren't working](//serverfault.com/questions/480551/logrotate-not-rotating-file-after-file-size-exceeds-the-limit/480556#480556).

The best approach here may be to leave the defaults of [`tomcat`](http://ports.su/www/tomcat/v8) as-is (which, in fact, are more friendly for various backup purposes, for example), and do the rotation with a simple script that uses file modification time to perform the rotation (e.g., `find /var/tomcat/logs/ -mtime +5 -name "*.log" -exec echo rm {} \;`, remove `echo` for the real thing).

Per [related question](//stackoverflow.com/a/23108631/1122270), you can also configure the above [`find`](http://mdoc.su/o/find.1) snippet within the `lastaction` / `endscript` directives of `logrotate`, or, better yet, put it directly into `cron` to run on your own time.

Other references:

- [Why does tomcat7 log into both catalina.out and catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log?](https://serverfault.com/questions/476647/why-does-tomcat7-log-into-both-catalina-out-and-catalina-yyyy-mm-dd-log/476656#476656)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183321/whats-the-easiest-way-to-rotate-nginx-log-files-monthly/15183322#15183322

Answer (score 1):

Just send logs to syslog, and write the logfiles with syslog then rotate as you wish.

Comment: 100 times this. But if you don't _want_ to (or can't...) use logrotate, you can also use [log4j 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) if you want "better" logging.

Comment: thanks, but I'm really looking for a simple way to do this using just tomcat configuration - it seems crazy that there is no way to change this behaviour especially since it breaks logrotate so badly

Comment: While I 100% agree with @Lenniey, I am not sure, how could you send the tomcat logs to syslog, or how could it be done easily. Java doesn't support unix sockets, and syslog happens with unix sockets (by default).

Comment: To get tomcat to log in system log, 1) a JNI-based (-> platform-dependent) addon should be installed, or syslogd should listen on a networked socket, too 2) a juli jar should be installed in the tomcat, and properly configured, which logs there. As far I know, nobody developed it until now.

Comment: @Lenniey I think, you have probably set up only the application log, but not the tomcat log. With it, you miss a lot of important debug/troubleshooting information.