# Change Tomcat's catalina log file name

Tags: logging, tomcat

I'd like to change Tomcat's (8.5) catalina log file name format for the current day. I want the current log file for today to be with no date in the name and be only catalina.log because I want to watch it in Eclipse in Log Viewer. Currently I have to remove the file from Log Viewer and add the one with the new date every day.
I have the server set up on Windows.
I don't want to turn off the logging in catalina or change the logging in any way - just the name of the log file. I didn't find any property for this or where this is set up.

**Clarification in case it's not clear**:
 I want the rotation to remain, I want the names for the archived files from previous days to remain the same. What I want to change is the name of the currently acitve log file from catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log to catalina.log and after its being archived to be renamed to catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log for the appropriate day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off all tomcat log rotation](https://serverfault.com/questions/892824/how-to-turn-off-all-tomcat-log-rotation)

Comment: No - this is about turning logging off - I want to change the name of the log file

Comment: No it's about turning off log _rotation_, which would keep one logfile with the same name forever.

Comment: You're right, my bad, but still this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Yes, because you changed it afterwards :)

Comment: Yeah.. I added some more clarification because I thought that it could be misunderstood